# Spring-boot-maven-plugin generates a defective manifest

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, manifest, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm experiencing a behavior whereby this configuration of **spring-boot-maven-plugin**:

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
.....
```

results in the following (shortened) manifest.mf file produced inside the jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Implementation-Title: submit-enrollment
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor-Id: c.z.services
Built-By: sl
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_76
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.5
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

which results in a defective jar impossible to run.

As soon as I remove the **pluginManagement** tag from the pom.xml, the resulting manifest changes to the following fuller version and all is good during the jar execution:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Implementation-Title: submit-enrollment
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor-Id: c.z.services
Built-By: sl
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_76
Start-Class: c.z.submit.enrollment.SubmitEnrollmentApplication
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.5
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.2.5.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

According to the plugin's [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), the pluginManagement tag is expected:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

So, what's the correct usage pattern of this plugin in the pom.xml file which produces correct deployable artifact?

Thanks!

Comment: So you work at pivotal? :-p  You need it in the plugin section, as well as the plugin management section.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas ;-)  Pivotal is what gets put their by the spring-boot-maven-plugin by default.  Would you happen to know how to change the Implementation-Vendor value?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? I find your report very puzzling.  When you remove the `pluginManagement` what version of the plugin is used?

Comment: Spring Boot just takes the value of your original manifest (created by the regular jar plugin) `Pivotal Software, Inc.` comes from the name of the organization of the parent pom. Just specify your own organization (see https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html)

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll: I was missing the plugin section (as pointed out by CarlosBribiescas comment) in my pom.xml and the behavior described was attributable to that.  Once I added  spring-boot-maven-plugin under both <pluginManagement> and <plugins>/<plugin> section it started to work as expected.  As for your second suggestion - adding <organization>/<name> in the pom.xml did the trick - thanks for the prompt response.  If it matters - I'm willing to approve the answers as accepted for posterity ;-)

Comment: I am not really answering your initial question. And to be clear, I still don't understand what your problem was with the "corrupted manifest". If you don't provide any version, it should still work even though you should provide the version has maven reminds you with a warning if you don't.